# Draw some rectangles on image usng HTML 5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas

In my web application I want the user to be able to draw some rectangles on an image, also change the size of the rectangles and drag and drop them. after that I have to get coordinates of rectangles and send them to server's database 

Is it better to create a canvas on a photo or load the image in canvas ? 
I don't write any code yet because I have no idea how to do this.

Any ideas,suggestions,links,libraries ?

Comment: This can be done with HTML5 Canvas, and it seems to me to be the best solution for the complete problem.

Comment: @shaahin did you get this working? I have a 100% same requirement I would like to know how you acheived it.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment said canvas is a good bet for this, but you'd need to do a fair bit of coding to get it working.

I actually have a tutorial on making Canvas [interactive by drawing rectangles and moving them around.](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful) It should give you a good start on this project.

There are also a few libraries, such as [fabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/), but that might be hard to get the coordinates out of without digging into the library.

Comment: Simon, I am afraid the link to the demo at the bottom of the tutorial is broken (error 404).

Comment: derp thanks, updated the link to point to github, I'll make sure its all up to date later tonight